# Getting different results while calculating the number of elements when passing an integer array to a function

Tags: c++

I was just trying to get the number of elements in an integer array. The following is the code :

```
#include <iostream>

int unsorted[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};

void PrintArrayAndSize(int arr[]);


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    // insert code here...

    long size = *(&unsorted + 1) - unsorted;

    std::cout<<"no of elements = " << size <<"\n";//sizeof(int);

    PrintArrayAndSize(unsorted);

    return 0;
}


void PrintArrayAndSize(int arr[])
{

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)

        std::cout<<arr[i]<<"\n";

    long size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;

    std::cout<<"no of elements = " << size <<"\n";//sizeof(int);
}
```

The following is the output. Its the same array but when I calculate the size in main I get the correct output. When I pass the array to a function and calculate, I get some other result.

no of elements = 9

9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

no of elements = 35182156444984

Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Unconventional naming of the variable `unsorted`... it is actually sorted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For arguments, arrays are passed as *pointers* (to the arrays first element). Even if using e.g. `int arr[]`. The compiler treats that as `int *arr`.

That means `&arr` is a pointer *to the pointer*, and not a pointer to the array.

If you want a function to know the size of an array, you should always pass that as an argument.

Or, since you're using C++, you could instead of plain C-style arrays use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Or use templates to be able to pass a reference to the array with auto-deduction of the array size (which is usable for `std::array` as well).

So my suggestion is that you do something like

```
template<size_t N>
void PrintArrayAndSize(std::array<int, N> const& arr)
{
    for (auto value : arr)
        std::cout << value << '\n';

    std::cout << "Array size is " << arr.size() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 9> a = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    PrintArrayAndSize(a);
}
```